# dnsmasq does not resolve local adresses

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, dnsmasq

I am setting up a dnsmasq server at the moment with the capabiltity of acting as a DHCP server. Ive done a basic setup yet. My goal was to have a DHCP Server here that also resolves names and makes them pingable.

DHCP works just fine, I get the Adresses in range, etc. But I cant ping other computers by name. Here is my config:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
filterwin2k
bind-interfaces
domain=nidhoegger.local
dhcp-range=192.168.42.100,192.168.42.250,36h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.42.1
```

my resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

The clients get the IP of the dnsmasq server as DNS, so that should be fine. What else can be the issue?

Comment: So in client's resolv.conf is your dhcp server ip right? Do you actually run also a DNS server on that machine?

Comment: dnsmasq acts as dns and dhcp server. and yes, there is the IP of the local DNS server where dnsmasq is running

Comment: How about this? https://blogging.dragon.org.uk/howto-setup-dnsmasq-as-dns-dhcp/ the config is way richer than you have. looks like you do not specify domain settings